# If a Psion of 15th level or higher with Psicrystal Affinity uses Channel Power to manifest True Mind Switch

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Channel power states that "The owner of the psicrystal can manifest powers through the psicrystal to a distance of up to 1 mile. The psicrystal is treated as the power’s originator, and all ranges are calculated from its location."

Since the power originates from the Psicrystal, if True body Switch is manifested, the Psycrystal and target would switch places upon failing a Will save. If you pay the extra power points the change will become permanent and the creature now trapped within the psicrystal can be broken and killed easily.

Your psicrystal is now that creature, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Originator” refers to the *location* that the effect is coming from, for the purposes of ranges and targeting. The ability does **not** make your psicrystal the *manifester* of the effect: that is still you. So you would still perform the swap with whatever creature fifteen miles away. If it made the psicrystal the manifester, it would *say that*.

Answer (score -1):

### Unclear

It's unclear what *exactly* 'originator' means in this context.  The clearest reading to me is 'treated as the manifester of the power'.  In that case, the 'you' language from [**True Mind Switch**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/mindSwitchTrue.htm) would apply to the psycrystal, and the psycrystal would gain control of the body of the target.

It would, however, probably lose any special abilities granted by being a Psycrystal, as 'Special' abilities and abilities based on a specific form are not retained.

It's worth noting that there are ways for a psycrystal to cast or count as the caster of True Mind Switch without this method.  So it's possible within the rules system, and this method, while cheesy, does appear to follow the intent and my best reading of the rules.

Enjoy your free Great Wyrm Gold with a fragment of your mind inside.